# Plotting a third degree regression line in matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

I'm having an issue when trying to plot a 3rd-order polynomial regression.
The code I have is:

```
figure
scatter(xtr, ytr, 'filled','b')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')

coef = polyfit(xtr, ytr, 3);
pp = polyval(coef,xtr);

hold on
plot(xtr,pp,'r-')
```

[image]

I don't understand what is wrong with how I'm plotting the line. My code works fine for polynomials of order 1.